# Adding new array in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an application that involves a somewhat complex user registration. Something similar to this.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({
  identity: '',
  people: [{
   name: '',
   address: [{
     street: '',
     city: ''
   }]
  }]
})

function addAddress(){
  setData({
      ...data,
      people: [
        ...data.people,
        {
          address: [
            ...data.people[0].address,
            {
              street: '',
              city: ''
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
}
```

When a user adds a new address to a person he is registering, he should add a new address to the person and keep the previous data. But it creates a new data array with just the address data, outside of the specified person.

Could someone help me how to do this insertion into the array?

Comment: Inside addAddress, I would expect you to search `people` for "the specified person" and add or modify their address.

Comment: I'd expect to see something like list:     `setData(data => { data.people.find(p=> p.name == "hello")?.address.push({ street:'', city:''}); return data; })` as @James said. How do you identify the person who's address you're adding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best solution i guess, but it should work

I'm using here `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to deep copy your previous data

```
function addAddress (newAddress) => {
  setData((previousData) => {
    let newData = JSON.stringify(previousData);
    newData=JSON.parse(newData);
    newData.people[0].address.push(newAddress);

    return (newData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed your suggestion, but when I enter something it returns the following error message "TypeError: Cannot add property 1, object is not extensible".

Comment: I modified the code in my answer with a deep copy of your previous data using JSON stringify and parse to simplify (but it's not the best practice to deep copy data )